# Why "space" is not supported in the ajax post method?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp-classic

Below is my html

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>New Page 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Data_Check()
{
var xmlHttp;

try
  {  
  xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  }
catch (e)
  { 
   try
    {    
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");   
     }
  catch (e)
    {   
     try
      {     
       xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   
          }
    catch (e)
      {      
      alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");      
      return false; 
           }    
           } 
            }
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
      {
      alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
      }
    }   

    var RES = document.getElementById("Remarks").innerHTML;
    var params ="RES="+RES;
    xmlHttp.open("POST","Data_Check.asp",true);       
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlHttp.send(params);

   }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<textarea id="Remarks" rows="5" name="Remarks" cols="79" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px">please, accept my submit form.</textarea>

<br>
<img id="Submit" onclick ="return Data_Check();" border="0" src="submit.png" width="145" height="28">
</body>
<img
</html>
```

Here i facing the problem is,

When i submit "Remarks" textarea innerhtml to my "Data_Check.asp"

```
<%
RES = Request.Form("RES")
%>
```

and this remarks save in my sql database.( database field is "Remarks_text" and datatype is "text")

In the data base textarea data is read ("please, accept my submit form.") textarea data with out space.

like this 
**please,acceptmysubmitform.**

I need to save 
**please, accept my submit form.**

hoping your support

Comment: just came across this thread. Please, if you have the time, go through some basic jQuery intro materials, and I believe you would feel in love with it. The idea is to hide browser implementation of the XMLHttpRequest :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try url encoding:

```
var RES = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Remarks").value);
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Spaces were being removed from my strings, for whatever reasons since this never happened before, but this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`document.getElementById("Remarks").innerHTML;`

to

`document.getElementById("Remarks").value;`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect spaces are not supported in URLs or HTTP headers, hence old URLs had `%20` instead of a space. Modern browsers and servers now do this behind the scenes.

I found replacing spaces with `%20` using `formValues = formValues.replace(/ /gi,"%20");` prior to sending solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is fixed!

Example :

`var dataString = "textcontent="+test.replace(/ /gi,"%20");`